# How to add Print buttom in a sheet to print other sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need a script to, adding a print button in a sheet1, to print the entire sheet2.

How can I do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can't really set up the print screen that way in google sheets right now but you can create a link to produce a pdf file of the sheet:

```
=hyperlink("docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"
      & "!!!WORKBOOK ID GOES HERE!!!"
      & "/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf"
      & "&size=LETTER"
      & "&portrait=true"
      & "&fitw=true"       
      & "&top_margin=0.50"              
      & "&bottom_margin=0.50"          
      & "&left_margin=0.50"             
      & "&right_margin=0.50"           
      & "&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false"
      & "&pagenum=false"
      & "&gridlines=false"
      & "&fzr=FALSE"      
      & "&gid="
      & "!!!SHEET2 GID HERE!!!","pdf of sheet2")
```

Feel free to edit the settings of the pdf output url to how you want it to look printed.